# tailwindcss navbar menu hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

This is my component Item component

```
const Item = ({ href, children, childs }) => {
  return (
    <li className="group relative">
      <Link href={href} passHref>
        <a className="relative flex items-center gap-x-[9px] text-[15px] font-medium text-olive transition-all group-hover:text-coral">
          <span>{children}</span>
        </a>
      </Link>

      {childs > 0 && (
        <ul className="absolute top-full left-0 mt-6 hidden min-w-[258px] bg-olive group-hover:block">
          {childs.map(({ title, href }, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <Link href={href} passHref>
                <a className="block px-[21px] py-[13px] text-[15px] font-medium text-darkGray hover:bg-[#F4F7D9]">
                  {title}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};
```

This is the result:
As you see I don't know how to fix the dropdown hovered issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  return (
    <li className="group relative">
      <Link href={href} passHref>
        <a className="relative flex items-center gap-x-[9px] text-[15px] font-medium text-olive transition-all group-hover:text-coral">
          <span>{children}</span>

          {childs && childs.length > 0 && (
            <span className="transition-transform group-hover:rotate-45">
              <ArrowDownRightIcon />
            </span>
          )}
        </a>
      </Link>

      {childs && childs.length > 0 && (
        <ul className="absolute top-full left-0 mt-6 hidden min-w-[258px] bg-olive after:absolute after:-top-6 after:h-6 after:w-full after:content-[''] group-hover:block">
          {childs.map(({ title, href }, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <Link href={href} passHref>
                <a className="block px-[21px] py-[13px] text-[15px] font-medium text-darkGray hover:bg-[#F4F7D9]">
                  {title}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Solved